# How to run background script of chrome extension on every web page page load?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a background script which runs on short keys and click on the extension icon but, now I want to run it on every web page load.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want it to do on each page load. Depending on that you may need a listener like chrome.tabs.onUpdated ([example](/a/50549591)) or an entirely separate [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: I need to tack a screenshot.  now I using this API "chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener"

Comment: Here I want to take a screenshot of every webpage, after refresh extension it automatically runs and takes a screenshot without a click on the extension icon. Hope You Understood now!

Comment: I see, but Chrome doesn't allow extensions to make screenshots silently without user confirmation to prevent malware from spying on users. AFAIK the only solution is to use [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) to send [Page.captureScreenshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-captureScreenshot) command, but that will show a warning panel about extension debugging above each tab.

Comment: Ah, you can hide the warning by running chrome with `--silent-debugger-extension-api` command line.

Answer (score 0):

The background script already loads on every page request. If your looking to update the data between the background script and content script in your background process you need to create two listeners, the second is usefull when multiple tabs are open. Remember data in your popup can be retrieved by simply calling `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(info.tabId, {
    message: 'DO_SOMETHING_MESSAGE'
  });
})

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(info.tabId, {
    message: 'DO_SOMETHING_MESSAGE'
  });
})
```

content.js should function similar to this.

```
const processContent = () => {
  // do whatever here.
  let data = {message: UPDATE_BACKGROUND_DATA}
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data);
}

// run when messages sent from background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message === 'DO_SOMETHING_MESSAGE') {
    processContent();
  }
});

// run onload
processContent();
```

And finally, back in your background script create a listener that listens for any updated data.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.message === UPDATE_BACKGROUND_DATA) {
    // update background vars
  }
})
```